# Let $\mathcal{C}$ = {$(a,b): - \infty \le a < b \le \infty$}.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, real-numbers, borel-sets

Let $\mathcal{C}$ = {$(a,b): - \infty \le a < b \le \infty$}.
Is it closed under complementation, countable union, countable increasing unions?

I could show that it is not closed under complementation as $(- \infty, \infty)^c =${$-\infty,\infty$} which is not in $\mathcal{C}$.
But what about unions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Is $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ an interval of the form $(a,b)$?

Comment: It is $(0,2)$\{1} right?

Comment: Yes. Is that a member of $\mathcal C$? The collection $\mathcal C$ is defined to be the collection of all open intervals.

Comment: No it is not a member . But what about countable increasing unions?

Comment: Try expressing an increasing union of intervals $\bigcup_n(a_n,b_n)$ in terms of the sequences $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$. I assume you know what is meant by an "increasing union".